# Globally Disable Back Button in Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

I know that is possible to disable by wrapping a widget with `WillPopScope`, but it's a pain do this with all widgets.

So, is there a way to Globally Disable Back Button in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, you can override **onBackPressed** in your **MainActivity.java** (that extends FlutterActivity in your app)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing
    // super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In Kotlin:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
  // do nothing
}
```

Comment: @son-tieu Can you complement by providing the path to this file, please?

Comment: For default new project, you can find it in: project_folder/android/app/src/main/kotlin/your/app/package/MainActivity.kt

Comment: For older project which using java: project_folder/android/app/src/main/java/your/app/package/MainActivity.java

Comment: MainActivity.kt: (8, 1): Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'top level function'

Comment: @rubStackOverflow you should override that method in your MainActivity not top level of file. (inside class block)